# tkinter.place() not working and window still blank

Tags: python, tkinter, methods, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-button

I have a problem with tkinter.place, why it is not working?

```
class KafeDaun(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.title("Kafe Daun-Daun Pacilkom v2.0 ")
        self.master.geometry("500x300")
        self.master.configure(bg="grey")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.btn_buat_pesanan = tk.Button(self, text = "Buat Pesanan", width = 20)
        self.btn_buat_pesanan.place(x = 250, y = 100)

        self.btn_meja = tk.Button(self, text = "Selesai Gunakan Meja", width = 20)
```

[image]

I still get this blank Frame even though already use tkinter.place on btn_buat_pesanan

I expect it to have a button on the exact location, like when using `tkinter.pack()` or `tkinter.grid()`. Do you have any suggestion
... ... ... ... ..

Comment: `place()` will not adjust the parent size, so the initial size of the frame will be 1x1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You have to pack the frame like this `self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`. Because the `place` did not change the parent size, that's why it didn't visible

```
import tkinter as tk
class KafeDaun(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.title("Kafe Daun-Daun Pacilkom v2.0 ")
        self.master.geometry("500x300")
        self.master.configure(bg="grey")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.btn_buat_pesanan = tk.Button(self, text = "Buat Pesanan", width = 20)
        self.btn_buat_pesanan.place(x = 250, y = 100)

        self.btn_meja = tk.Button(self, text = "Selesai Gunakan Meja", width = 20)
app =tk.Tk()


s = KafeDaun(app)
app.mainloop()
```

Or you can set the width and height of the frame. `super().__init__(master, width=<width>, height=<height>)`